Restriction of Brauer characters in GAP
Let $p$ be a prime.
Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a $p'$-subgroup of $G$.
Let $\varphi\in \mathrm{IBr}_p(G)$.
I would like to restrict $\varphi$ to $H$ by GAP.
My idea is to extend $\varphi$ to a class function $f$ of $G$ such that $f=\varphi$ on the $p$-regular elements but $f$ vanishes on the $p$-singular elements.
Then restrict the class function $f$ to $H$.
However, I don't know how to extend $\varphi$ to the class function $f$ of $G$ by using GAP.
So, my question is: how to restrict $\varphi$ to $H$ by GAP?
A general question is: how to restrict $\varphi$ to any subgroup of $G$ by GAP?

If you have a fusion map from the subgroup you should be able to simply restrict the brauer character. D you have created $\varphi$ as a Brauer character (and not just a list of values)?

For instance, let $G=\mathrm{PSL}(2,17)$ and $H\in \mathrm{Syl}_3(G)$. I would like to restrict a $17$-Brauer character to $H$. I have tried the command FusionConjugacyClasses, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Are the character tables from a library or did you create them yourself? Are groups associated? Did you store a fusion map in them?

Here is my code: gap> g:=AtlasGroup("L2(17)");;
gap> p:=SylowSubgroup(g,3);;
gap> fus:=FusionConjugacyClasses(p,g);
[ 1, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 3, 9, 3 ]
gap> ctg:=BrauerTable(g,17);;
gap> ctp:=BrauerTable(p,17);;
gap> StoreFusion(ctp,ctg,fus); (Here is where the error occurs.)

When I try this ctg is not a Brauer table but fail.

Could you show me an example on the restriction of Brauer characters? @ahulpke
